# How to create and run a development build of an application using create-react-app configuration

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

`npm run build` creates production build of the project. How do I create development build? I'm using [gradle-node-plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin) to build the artifact. The project has standard *create-react-app* configuration.

Answer (score 28):

This is not really doable with just `create-react-app`, there is an open issue [Here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/790) and it doesn't look like it will be added anytime soon.

However, you can use a package called `dotenv` for that, following are the steps you should take:

- Install `dotenv` (make sure to add `save dev`) `npm install dotenv-cli --save-dev`
- In package.json scripts section add new script: `"build:dev": "dotenv -e .env.development react-scripts build",`
- And you can build for development with `npm run build:dev`

---

PS: if you want to avoid mistakenly deploying dev builds to production (as mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2880#issuecomment-319120228)) you can add `build:prod` to package.json and disable the regular `build` command, see code:

```js
"build:dev": "dotenv -e .env.development react-scripts build",
"build:prod": "dotenv -e .env.production react-scripts build",
"build": "echo \"Please use build:dev or build:prod \" && exit 1",
```

Also note that `process.env.NODE_ENV` will still be `production` but it'll load your .env.development file

Comment: Worked for me, unfortunately (and to my surprise), the build time wasn't noticeably different, so I reverted back to normal

Comment: its annoying that even after so many years, we have to jump through hoops to get something simple like a debug/development mode build!.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks, @Moses. This is an extension to the answer posted by Moses Schwartz. You can also make the build pick the environment files dynamically by exporting the value of the environment(development, test, production) in the bash shell. And then you don't have to have different build commands for different environments.

You can use this in your package.json

```
"start": "dotenv -e .env react-scripts start",
"build": "dotenv -e .env.${REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT} react-scripts build",
```

So when your run npm start, it will pick the environment values from .env
and when you run npm run build, it will pick the environment values from .env.{REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT}

To define the REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT, you can do:

```
export REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT="development" or 
export REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT="test" or 
export REACT_APP_ENVIRONMENT="production"
```

Hope this helps. This will help in staging the react application for multiple environments.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @Tx_monster comment

[github.com/Nargonath/cra-build-watch](https://github.com/Nargonath/cra-build-watch)

*A script for create-react-app that writes development builds to the disk*

```
npm install -D cra-build-watch

package.json:
{
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "cra-build-watch"
  }
}

npm run watch
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, cra-build-watch hos not been maintained in 2 years and is already broken with CRA4 and 5

Comment: much like CRA itself !!!! 