# Create a react "development" build

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

What's the best way to create a development build bundle for a create-react-app project?

`npm run build` builds something that's buggy in ways that development isn't and it ignores my NODE_ENV setting

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create and run a development build of an application using create-react-app configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517422/how-to-create-and-run-a-development-build-of-an-application-using-create-react-a)

Comment: Thanks, that's not too promising. I guess I have to try to fix production issues

Answer (score 3):

This works for the react-scripts 5.0.1:

1. Install react-app-rewired: `npm install react-app-rewired`
2. Replace the `build` script in your `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "react-app-rewired build"
}
```

3. Create the `config-overrides.js` file in the root folder of your project.

```js
module.exports = function override(config) {
  config.mode = 'development';
  config.optimization.minimize = false;
  return config;
};
```

If you want to create two build modes you can add a condition that checks the mode.

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "cross-env react-app-rewired build",
  "build:dev": "cross-env DEV_MODE=true react-app-rewired build",
}
```

```js
module.exports = function override(config) {
  if (process.env.DEV_MODE) {
    config.mode = 'development';
    config.optimization.minimize = false;
  }
  return config;
};
```

Comment: ```react-app-rewired``` worked for me for react-scripts 5 unlike many other solutions floating around. However, the part about ```cross-env DEV_MODE=true``` did not, so i was not able to reproduce the second half of this answer.

Comment: @SkyNT you would also need to install cross-env, i.e: npm install --save-dev cross-env