Testing React + Firebase with emulator
I have a Firebase project where I'm using Firebase Functions and Hosting, and React for the frontend. During firebase init, I set build as my hosting directory, which is created by npm run build.
For local testing, I run firebase emulators:start with watch "npm run build".
However, the build process takes some time and React doesn't log full error messages in the minified production build.
Is there a better way to setup the development environment?
Like can I configure Firebase Emulator to use the public folder directly from React?

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58517422
